# Can "token" generated using "Paseto Token" be decrypted and viewed like "JWT Token"?

Tags: go, encryption, oauth, jwt, sts-securitytokenservice

I am using "Platform agnostic Security Token" for oAuth in Golang - https://github.com/o1egl/paseto

I am not able to understand, why this is better than JWT even after reading README

My Major Question is:

1. Can "token" generated be altered like "JWT" and pass modified or tampered data?
2. Can "token" generated using "paseto" be decrypted and viewed like "JWT"?

Paseto library above uses "SET" and "GET" method inside their JSONToken method. Is that how we can verify authenticity of the user?

Sample Code:

```
symmetricKey := []byte("YELLOW SUBMARINE, BLACK WIZARDRY") // Must be 32 bytes
now := time.Now()
exp := now.Add(24 * time.Hour)
nbt := now

jsonToken := paseto.JSONToken{
        Audience:   "test",
        Issuer:     "test_service",
        Jti:        "123",
        Subject:    "test_subject",
        IssuedAt:   now,
        Expiration: exp,
        NotBefore:  nbt,
        }
// Add custom claim to the token    
jsonToken.Set("data", "this is a signed message")
footer := "some footer"

v2 := paseto.NewV2()

// Encrypt data
token, err := v2.Encrypt(symmetricKey, jsonToken, footer)
// token = "v2.local.E42A2iMY9SaZVzt-WkCi45_aebky4vbSUJsfG45OcanamwXwieieMjSjUkgsyZzlbYt82miN1xD-X0zEIhLK_RhWUPLZc9nC0shmkkkHS5Exj2zTpdNWhrC5KJRyUrI0cupc5qrctuREFLAvdCgwZBjh1QSgBX74V631fzl1IErGBgnt2LV1aij5W3hw9cXv4gtm_jSwsfee9HZcCE0sgUgAvklJCDO__8v_fTY7i_Regp5ZPa7h0X0m3yf0n4OXY9PRplunUpD9uEsXJ_MTF5gSFR3qE29eCHbJtRt0FFl81x-GCsQ9H9701TzEjGehCC6Bhw.c29tZSBmb290ZXI"

// Decrypt data
var newJsonToken paseto.JSONToken
var newFooter string
err := v2.Decrypt(token, symmetricKey, &newJsonToken, &newFooter)
```

Now, if you see there is code: `jsonToken.Set("data", "this is a signed message")` and we can get that value in Decrypt data at the end where `newJsonToken` variable is created.

We can get the value of "data" key using: `newJsonToken.Get("data")`.

But is above data "verifiable" and can't be tampered or modified on user's end?

Like in JWT debugger at JWT.io, People can tamper data and know the algorithm and pass "modified" data.

Can user do the same with my generated token as well? Can they decode and pass tampered data? or they can't decode data or view actual data at all?

Comment: How can people tamper JWT data? It is signed. You'd need to know the secret key (and yeah, if that's not secret then of course everything breaks down).

Comment: If you can view the contents of the token on jwt.io, then it is not **encrypted** but just **encoded** (base64url encoding), hence there is nothing to **decrypt** but just to **decode**. If you need encrypted data, you can also use JWE, the encrpted variant of JWT.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1 - Can "token" generated be altered like "JWT" and pass modified or tampered data?

Note that token cannot be "altered" either using PASETO or JWT without knowing the signing key (which should of course be secret).

The fact you mention about being able to **view** the JWT token data in JWT.io page is because data is not encrypted (so you can see it without the key).

But token is signed, so if you modify any value and don't have the key, you won't be able to sign it back and the token receiver will note the token is not valid when trying to verify it.

> 2 - Can "token" generated using "paseto" be decrypted and viewed like "JWT"?

It depends on how you generate the PASETO token.

See here:

https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-paragon-paseto-rfc-00.html#rfc.section.2

Format for the token is `version.purpose.payload`.

And from the docs:

> The payload is a string that contains the token's data. In a local token, this data is encrypted with a symmetric cipher. In a public token, this data is unencrypted.

So if you generate the token as in the code snippet you posted (local token, with a symmetric key), then payload will be encrypted (you won't be able to see it unless you know the symmetric key and use that one to decrypt it).

If you use a public/private key pair, then payload will not be encrypted, so you'll be able to **see it** without the key (but you'll not be able to change it and sign it again without knowing the private key).

Comment: Without secret signed string user anyhow would not be able to pass tamper data and get verified.